# mysql export separate create table and alter

Tags: mysql, database, import, export

I'm currently trying to find a way to separate the mysql export function (using phpmyadmin and/or shell)

Following situation: 
I have two databases which were the same at some state but over time only one got updated. So for example:
 - database1 has table "users" with columns "UID" and "username"
 - database2 has table "users" with columns "UID" "username" and "status"

Now i want to export database2 and import it to database1. database2 contains data I **DONT** need anymore. But database1 contains important data. So I need something that gives me the possibility to somehow "merge" these databases without data loss on database1 and without merging data from database2.

- The merge should look if the table exists, if not -> create it
- The merge should look if the columns exist in the table, if not -> create it

What I have tried so far:
I've first tried it with the inbuilt PHPmyadmin export function (advanced options). This would give me the following result:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `UID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When I import this, of course, nothing special will happen since the table already exists and so the 'status' column does not get created.
On my research I found a possibility to export a database separated from table creation using shell using the command (blacked out database name and user/pass):

```
mysqldump -t --insert-ignore --skip-opt -u USER -p PASSWORD -h 127.0.0.1 database > database.sql
```

But this gives me an insert option with data (which I dont need)

```
INSERT  IGNORE INTO `users` VALUES (1,"bla",1);
```

Is there any different possibility?
Sure I know I could write it by hand to alter the columns into the table but it sure has to be automatic since its not only the table I named in the example.

To be 100% clear what I'm trying to achieve, a pseudo handwritten sql script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'users';
For every column -> IF NOT EXISTS column in 'users' -> ALTER TABLE 'users' ADD column def;
```

Comment: You can use one of schema comparison tools: https://dbmstools.com/categories/schema-compare-tools/mysql

Comment: *but over time only one got updated.* Does the actions "add new table" and "add new field into existing table" are the only actions? No added triggers, functions, etc., no altered fieldnames, constraints, indices, etc., no another changes?

Comment: @Akina I've only added tables and columns. No columns were renamed, deleted or anything else

Comment: If so create a procedure which performs needed upgrade using the info from INFORMATION_SCHEMA and prepared statements. It won't be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQLWorkBench as well. Look [video instruction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydaXej1pzYk)